# no editor found (editor path = /usr/bin/editor) running visudo

Tags: docker, sudo

I created a ubuntu docker container and when I try to edit the sudoers file I get the following message.

```
root@8c8a8ff68234:~# sudo visudo
visudo: no editor found (editor path = /usr/bin/editor)
```

Create command and run command:-

```
docker run -id ubuntu
docker exec -ti 8c8a8ff68234 /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 4):

You are already root, so no need to use sudo.

Also, you have no vim pre-installed in ubuntu base image. So you need to install it with `apt-get install vim`. Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install vim
```

That will set the `editor` properly. To use `visudo`

```
visudo
```

Comment: `visudo` is a bit safer than `vim /etc/sudoers` (even if one is root!), as the former will prevent the file from being saved in an invalid format.